# Can't pull user posts with app credentials even though user has authorized app

Tags: facebook, authentication

I have an app and a user who has added that app and authorized it with permissions: read_stream and user_status. I've got a node js app running that's trying to make an API call (using only the app credentials) to pull the user's posts but I get the following error: 
"A user access token is required to request this resource."

How can this be done without having to have the user login every time I want to pull their feed?

Answer (score 0):

It can't; you need a user access token to access that user's data - the error message is fairly clear about this I think.

Check the [Authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation - you should be storing the users' access tokens and using those to make API calls on behalf of those users

Comment: The user's access token will expire though after a while right? I'd like to have something that runs forever without having the user come back to login

Comment: The user's access token is supposed to expire, you can get a maximum of 60 days before they need to come back, and each time they come back the 60 days is reset